# 2D Collision Detection Resolution

Tags: c++, 2d, collision-detection

I've been writing this collision detection system using a tutorial from an article I read and I just cannot for the life of me get it to function 100% correctly.
Here's the code for starters:

```
BoundingBox aBox;
aBox.Convert(a);
BoundingBox bBox;
bBox.Convert(b);

Vector2 aMin = aBox.GetTopLeft();
Vector2 aMax = aBox.GetBotRight();
Vector2 bMin = bBox.GetTopLeft();
Vector2 bMax = bBox.GetBotRight();

Vector2 minDistance;

float left = (bMin.x - aMax.x);
float right = (bMax.x - aMin.x);
float top = (bMin.y - aMax.y);
float bottom = (bMax.y - aMin.y);

// Check for intersection internally
if (left > 0 || right < 0) return;
if (top > 0 || bottom < 0) return;

// Find the minDistance
if (abs(left) < right)
    minDistance.x = left;
else
    minDistance.x = right;

if (abs(top) < bottom)
    minDistance.y = top;
else
    minDistance.y = bottom;

// Null axis with biggest value
if (abs(minDistance.x) < abs(minDistance.y))
    minDistance.y = 0;
else
    minDistance.x = 0;
```

The problem right now is that the character is fine walking and hugging the top of a block and the bottom of a block, but once he has to walk UP two blocks, he gets stuck in between them. Coincidentally, walking down works perfectly fine. Just wondering if anyone has a solution to this problem, it would be much appreciated!

Here's a gif to better display the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, this might be more of a workaround than an actual fix, but when processing your input, you can check if there is room in the direction you are moving to.

If you move to the top left direction, you can check if there is room to the left, and if there is not, only apply the vertical component of the movement. Same applies to four directions.

Most of these kind of errors come from how rouding numbers work, and if you want a consistent and nice behaviour, working on how to avoid these rounding-number situations, like in the example I just gave you.